# Не работает dbclick js

Tags: javascript

Начинаю учить javascript. Делаю крестики-нолики. Хочу сделать так чтобы при нажатии на td появлялся крестик, а при двойном нажатии -- нолик.

```js
var one = document.querySelector("#one");

one.addEventListener('click', function() {
  one.textContent = 'X';
});

one.addEventListener('dbclick', function() {
  one.textContent = 'O';
});
```

```css
td {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="one"></td>
    <td id="two"></td>
    <td id="three"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="four"></td>
    <td id="five"></td>
    <td id="six"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="seven"></td>
    <td id="eight"></td>
    <td id="nine"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Когда нажимаю один раз: работает, появляется крестик. Но когда делаю dbclick не работает. Как это исправить?

Comment: Двойной клик - это два быстрых одиночных клика. Теперь задай себе вопрос: как это в таком случае должно работать?

Comment: Неудачная реализация. Лучше, например, ПКМ переключать крестик-нолик, а ЛКМ уже ставить. В целом, игра в крестики-нолики в одну будку - как-то странно сама по себе :))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ничего переключать не надо. Игра предполагает очередность. Нажали `х`, следующее нажатие `0` - переключать автоматом надо игрока.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg зависит от задумки автора ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: А как сделать проверку на нажатие левой кнопки мыши через addEventListener?

Comment: @VasikPro - https://learn.javascript.ru/mouse-clicks

Comment: У вас просто опечатка в названии события - в dbclick не хватает l. Если исправить, то ставятся и крестики и нолики вполне себе приемлемо.

Answer (score 1):

Обработка как одиночных, так и двойных кликов (на одном и том же элементе) - достаточно просто реализуется через отложенное выполнение, по таймауту:

```js
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (!evt.target.matches('td') || evt.target.textContent) return;   // прерываем выполнение если клик не по ячейке, или если в ячейке уже есть отметка
  const td = evt.target, 
        timeoutId = td.dataset.timeout;    // пробуем считать ID таймаута из data-атрибута ячейки
  clearTimeout(+timeoutId);                // в любом случае сразу отменим запланированное выполнение (мы уже узнали, "первый ли клик" попыткой чтения ID таймаута из атрибута)
  if (timeoutId)                           // если таймаут был выставлен (есть его ID), значит был клик - и это уже действие двойного клика!
    takeCell(td, 'O');
  else                                     // иначе (ID таймаута нет), это "первый" клик - тогда запланируем отметку Х по короткому таймауту (в течение которого можно успеть кликнуть второй раз)...
    td.dataset.timeout = setTimeout(() => takeCell(td, 'X'), 200);   // и запоминаем ID таймаута в data-атрибуте, чтобы можно было отменить (если пользователь кликнет второй раз)
  
  function takeCell(cell, mark) {          // вспомогательная функция "взятия" ячейки игрового поля (для сокращения повторений в коде, и повышения его читаемости)
    cell.textContent = mark; 
    delete cell.dataset.timeout;           // при отметке, в любом случае удаляем ID таймаута из атрибута (т.к. сам таймаут на данном этапе уже будет снят в любом случае)
  }; 
});
```

```css
td {
  width: 1em; height: 1em;
  font: 100px/1 sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="one"></td>
    <td id="two"></td>
    <td id="three"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="four"></td>
    <td id="five"></td>
    <td id="six"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="seven"></td>
    <td id="eight"></td>
    <td id="nine"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

В примере используется делегирование обработки событий - один общий обработчик (добавленный элементу таблицы) "ловит" все всплывающие события клика которые возникли и на самом элементе, и на его дочерних элементах.

Вызов `clearTimeout` даже когда таймаута нет, без предварительных проверок - вполне нормально, стандартное поведение функции позволяет это (никаких ошибок не возникнет).
Равно как и оператор `delete` не бросает ошибок когда предпринимается попытка удаления несуществующего свойства (в данном случае, этим оператором удаляется свойство объекта `dataset`, что повлечет удаление и data-атрибута элемента). Безусловно пользоваться этим оператором - тоже нормально.

*// Для более удобного чтения комментариев в коде примера, советую развернуть его на всю страницу.*